# AWS IAM Role Policy Issue on Media Convert Service [ Cannot open input file [Failed to read data: AssumeRole failed]]]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-media-convert, aws-elemental

I am struggling with AWS IAM Role Policies, I am following a tutorial for Lambda function to read from s3 bucket event when a new file is uploaded and send it to AWS MediaConvert to convert the video file.
Lambda function is being able to read from s3 in test but it fails the job at MediaConvert.

I have set the policies to the roles and also gave inline policies but still I am unable to get it working.

[AWS Elemental MediaConvert Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Yoi.png)

Policies set for IAM ROLE

[IAM Policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EGr8.png)

Json for inline policy

> lambda-s3-policy-inlinepolicy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ExampleStmt",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::aws-mybucket-01/*"
        ]
    }
]
 }
```

Policy Summary
[PolicySummaryImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn1vk.png)

> VodLambdaRole

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "Logging"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::myAccountID:role/my-lambda-role"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "PassRole"
    },
    {
        "Action": [
            "mediaconvert:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "MediaConvertService"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::myAccountID:role/my-lambda-role"
    }
]
}
```

[PolicySummary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov3KF.png)

Comment: I am a little confused... you mention an AWS Lambda function, but the error is appearing in the MediaConvert console. So where is the error originating? (I am familiar with IAM, but not with MediaConvert.) Does MediaConvert access the S3 object itself, or does it trigger an AWS Lambda function to access the S3 object?

Comment: the mediaConvert access the s3 object itself and outputs it to the s3 bucket after converting videos. Error is originating at MediaConvert - Error 1434 which is IAM Issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that the IAM Role assigned to the MediaConvert job has a **Trust Policy** that trusts MediaConvert:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "mediaconvert.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is normally generated automatically when you create an IAM Role in the management console and select **MediaConvert** as the Service.

Comment: Thanks John, it worked. I had to add mediaconvert into Trust Policies

Comment: Great! Please mark this as the accepted answer so that future readers can identify the solution.